# "Failed to download repository information" when trying to change mirrors

Tags: apt, 16.04, software-center, update-manager, repository

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my machine, however when trying to perform sudo apt-get update I got the following message:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/InRelease  Connection timed out after 120000 milliseconds
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

After some research I thought it would be useful to change my download mirror, however after selecting the recommended mirror and trying to update I get the error message:

> Failed to download repository information.Check your Internet connection.

with the following details:

```
  W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file. 
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
W:Failed to fetch https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/InRelease  Connection timed out after 120000 milliseconds
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found 
W:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any idea how I might solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is the PPAs mentioned in the error message, not the official repositories mirror. Either disable or remove them altogether. Changing the mirror has no impact whatsoever.

Comment: Both answers were useful! Problem solved, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the PPAs mentioned in the error message, not the official repositories mirror:

```
https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/InRelease

http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
```

Either disable or remove them altogether. Changing the mirror has no impact whatsoever.

Additional information: [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)